# Decrement the counter in javascript when hyperlink is typed in a TextArea

Tags: javascript

I have a textArea in which the Text will be typed and when text is typed the counter will be decreased by 1 for each character typed.. but I want when the landing link is typed in the textArea the counter will be decrement by exactly 16 and after that when normal text is typed again it will be decremented by 1 for each character .... any kind of help will be appreciated thanks

**TextArea**

```js
var maxLimit = 160;
$(document).ready(function(e) {
 $('#msgArea').keyup(function() {
  var lengthCount = this.value.length;
  if (lengthCount > maxLimit) {
   this.value = this.value.substring(0, maxLimit);
   var charactersLeft = maxLimit - lengthCount + 1;
   $('#msgArea').css('background-color', '#FFFF00');
  } else {
   var charactersLeft;
   var textmsg = document.getElementById('msgArea').value;
   var pattern = new RegExp(
    '((http|https)(://))?([a-zA-Z0-9]+[.]{1}){2}[a-zA-z0-9]+(/{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*/?',
    'i'
   );
   if (pattern.test(textmsg)) {
    lengthCount = lengthCount - 16;
    charactersLeft = maxLimit - lengthCount;
   } else {
    charactersLeft = maxLimit - lengthCount;
    $('#spnCharLeft').text(charactersLeft + ' Characters left');
   }
  }
  $('#spnCharLeft').css('display', 'block');
  if (lengthCount < maxLimit) {
   $('#msgArea').css('background-color', '#fff');
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
  <label>Message</label>
  <textarea id="msgArea" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
  <span id="spnCharLeft"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Please fix the snippet so it works and reproduces your issue.

Comment: the code snippet is now working fine

Comment: What is the meaning of landing link is typed in the textArea ? can you plese explain?

Comment: means just simple link i mean https://www.facebook.com or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var maxLimit = 160;
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('#msgArea').keyup(function() {
    var spanCharLeft = $('#spnCharLeft');
    var charactersLeft;
    var textmsg = this.value;
    var lengthCount = textmsg.length;
    var pattern = new RegExp(
      '((http|https)(://))?([a-zA-Z0-9]+[.]{1}){2}[a-zA-z0-9]+(/{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*/?',
      'ig'
    );
    var matches = textmsg.match(pattern);
    if (!matches) {
      matches = [];
    }
    matches.forEach(matched_string => {
      lengthCount = lengthCount - matched_string.length + 16;
    });

    charactersLeft = maxLimit - lengthCount;
    spanCharLeft.text(charactersLeft + ' Characters left');
    if (lengthCount < maxLimit) {
      $('#msgArea').css('background-color', '#fff');
    } else {
     this.value = this.value.substring(0, maxLimit);
      spanCharLeft.text('0' + ' Characters left');
      $('#msgArea').css('background-color', '#fff000');
    }

    $('#msgArea').css('display', 'block');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
  <label>Message</label>
  <textarea id="msgArea" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
  <span id="spnCharLeft"></span>
</div>
```

This should do it. Make note of the use of `matches = textmsg.match(pattern)`. You need to parse your string for each match of the pattern and then increase the `lengthCount` appropriately `lengthCount = lengthCount - matched_string.length + 16`. Also note that I've changed the regex to use the `g` global flag.

PS: I realise that this part is ugly

```
if(!matches) {
    matches = [];
}
```

I would appreciate edits on that

Comment: @Inam Running the snippet above seems to be running fine to me...are you sure you are testing it with the right text? Your regex requires your links to be of the form `foo.bar.baz`

Comment: thank you sir its working but there is one problem in it the background color is supposed to be yellow when 160 characters is reached but it gets yellow before it can you fix it ?

Comment: I have fixed it, and also refactored the code to follow a more logical pace. If this fixes the issue please upvote the answer.

Comment: thank you soo much sir it is now working but can't upvote the answer my reputation is less than 14

Comment: My mistake..i meant accept it as the correct answer..upvoting is irrelevant in this case